# Decals not displaying in Autodesk Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

When using the Autodesk Viewer, decals do not seem to display as expected. The image above has the decal displaying correctly (not rendered in Autodesk Viewer), and the image below has no decal (rendered in Autodesk viewer).

Why is this so, and how can decals be made to work in Autodesk Viewer?

Source files [here](https://grabcad.com/library/audio-clock-generator-pcb-1).

[image: Decal showing]

[image: No decal showing]

Comment: Which file format are you using? Forge will not import textures by default for most of the formats today which might be the issue there. But will for few file format like Fusion360. There is a workaround, you can reapply the texture to the fragId like shown on this [example](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions/Viewing.Extension.Fader/Viewing.Extension.Fader.Core.js).

Comment: What line number is the code you explained in your linked example? I'm using the step file located here https://grabcad.com/library/audio-clock-generator-pcb-1

Comment: Any updates @cyrille?

Comment: I'll write an example for you -

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code sample. I imported the STEP file on Forge, and copied the RefdFile_1.png file on my node.js server.

```
var attenuationVertexShader =`
  varying vec2 vUv;
  varying vec3 vPosition;
  void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
  }
  ` ;

var attenuationFragmentShader = `
  varying vec2 vUv;
  uniform sampler2D checkerboard;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(checkerboard, vec2 (vUv.x * 0.1263, vUv.y * 0.166)) ;
  }
` ;

var dbId =4 ;
var fragId =0 ;
var texturePath ="/RefdFile_1.png" ;
var material =null ;

oViewer =new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D ($("#viewer") [0], {}) ; // With toolbar
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer (options, function () {
    oViewer.initialize () ;
    oViewer.addEventListener (Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, function (event) {
        oViewer.fitToView (true) ;
        setTimeout (function () { oViewer.autocam.setHomeViewFrom (oViewer.navigation.getCamera ()) ; }, 1000) ;
        setTimeout (createTexture, 500) ;
    }) ;
    oViewer.setGroundReflection (false) ;
    oViewer.setGroundShadow (false) ;
    oViewer.load (myurn) ;
}) ;

function createTexture () {
    var loader =new THREE.TextureLoader () ;
    loader.load (texturePath, function (texture) {
        texture.minFilter =THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter ; // THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter
        texture.magFilter =THREE.LinearFilter ;

        var uniforms ={
            checkerboard: {
                type: 't',
                value: texture
            }
        } ;
        material =new THREE.ShaderMaterial ({
          uniforms: uniforms,
          vertexShader: attenuationVertexShader,
          fragmentShader: attenuationFragmentShader,
          side: THREE.DoubleSide
        }) ;
        oViewer.impl.matman ().removeMaterial ('shaderMaterial') ;
        oViewer.impl.matman ().addMaterial ('shaderMaterial', material, true) ;
        var floor_mesh_render =oViewer.impl.getRenderProxy (oViewer.model, fragId) ;
        oViewer.model.getFragmentList ().setMaterial (fragId, material) ;
        oViewer.impl.invalidate (true) ;
    }) ;
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks cyrille. can you link to your repository with the full working code example, not just a snippet?

Comment: furthermore how did you extract `RefdFile_1.png`?

Comment: Hi Cyrille, can you please link the repository containing your working code sample?

Comment: Hi @sabrehagen, I will, but travelling this week - give me few more days