# Texture of 3D model in FBX extension in Autodesk forge not visible

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I have uploaded a model with texture in a folder on A360 in FBX extension. At the time of checking view of model in this link "https://dm.autodesk.io" the texture of model not showing only default materials color are available there.

Please suggest how can i upload FBX with texture ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this might be an interesting question for the autodesk support team, it doesn't seem to be related to programming. StackOverflow is about programming and tooling problems, so I'm voting to close your question as off-topic.

Comment: i understand but it's related to model derivative API that's why i asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API does not extract material, nor textures for FBX files today (as the time of this post). It might in future, but have no ETA on this. This has been a long time request since Forge came out. If the goal is to show textures in the viewer, you can take a look to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513250/decals-not-displaying-in-autodesk-viewer/43682009#43682009) for a workaround.