# Forge, translate fbx file, but viewer don't have any texture

Tags: autodesk-forge

translate fbx file, but viewer don't have any texture.

my fbx file(17MB) madeby contextcapture. ( LiDAR )

fbx file's texture is fine. i checked by windows viewer and navisworks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API still does not extract material, nor textures for FBX files today (as the time of this post).

Please also refer the answer to this post at [Texture of 3D model in FBX extension in Autodesk forge not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333409/texture-of-3d-model-in-fbx-extension-in-autodesk-forge-not-visible)