# forge viewer does not show textture

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to get the material of the seleted dbId, here is the code:

```
const fragList = viewer.model.getFragmentList()
const fragIds = getFragIds(viewer.model, dbId)
fragIds.forEach((fragId) => {
  const material = fragList.getMaterial(fragId)
}
```

I found that there is `bumpMap` key in `material`, which represent the `texture`, but the texture did not show in viewer.

I wander to know why?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the time of this post, the Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API does not always extract textures for all formats. For example, textures and materials are not supported for FBX / STEP, but are for Revit, ...
It is possible to reapply textures using the viewer API though. Take a look to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513250/decals-not-displaying-in-autodesk-viewer/43682009#43682009) for an example.