# The pictures (JPEG file) in BIM model are not shown in Forge Viewer

Tags: jpeg, viewer, forge

I create BIM model and place the pictures (JPEG file) on the model's wall using 'place decal' function and change the graphic display option to 'realistic'. The result is as picture 1.
[image]

After that, I upload model to Forge viewer. However the pictures are not shown.

[image]

My questions are:

1) Why are the pictures in my revit model not shown in Forge viewer? How can I fix this?

2) If I can fix and the pictures are shown, can I change or replace the pictures in Forge Viewer later?

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Re 1: it's possible that decals in Revit models are currently not supported by the Forge Model Derivative service. I will talk to the engineering team and update this answer when I hear back from them. In the meantime, double check whether the decal image is *embedded* in the Revit file or *referenced* externally. If the image is *referenced*, you would have to include it with the *.rvt file in a zip archive when uploading & translating it in Forge.

Re 2: modifying textures of existing objects in Forge Viewer is possible but more involved. It would be easier to create new geometry (for example, using [SceneBuilder](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/SceneBuilder/)), and overlay the existing decals.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I'm looking forward to hear from you soon. Anyway, I would like to use BIM model to create virtual art galley on website like what Louvre Museum did. Moreover, I would like to be able to change the art piece also. I'm trying to use Forge but it might not be the right answer. Could you please suggest what I should use with BIM model to create the said virtual art gallery. Thanks again.

Comment: I believe Forge is the best approach to bring BIM models to the web. The rest of the content (e.g., the actual art on the walls) can be included into the viewer scene dynamically, using something like the SceneBuilder class mentioned in the answer, or a more basic approach: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/custom-geometry/.

Comment: Decals on Revit are not supported as of today (REVIT-119615). In the meantime, you can still apply decals using that [technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513250/decals-not-displaying-in-autodesk-viewer).